# How to validate azure resource naming conventions using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to check the name (for example azure vnet) provided in script to validate for azure vnet naming convention (Like it should not have any special character and length 2-64)

I am using below code but it is not working if string $name has special character in it.

It is working only for 0-9 and a-z.

```
$name = "zzz"
$name -cmatch "^[0-9a-z]*$"
```

Need a code to check a string which has for special character.
If it has special character it should return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$name = "hello@"
if($name -match '[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
{
    Write-Host "special character found"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "special character not found"
}
```

Comment: what is difference between "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" and "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
keeping ^ out of square bracket...what difference it will make?
Thanks :)

Comment: In a regular expression the metacharacter ^ means "not". Characters inside the brackets are a NON-matching set. Any occurrence of any character EXCEPT a-z,A-Z,0-9.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, if there is a special character in name, it will return true.

```
$name = "_"
$name -notmatch "[0-9a-zA-Z]"
```

Comment: what is use of ^,*,$ in "^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$"
can we use something like this to test everything "^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$#@%&" (this is not working)

Comment: @Akshay Yes, you can, but you need to add these characters in []. Like [0-9a-z$%@]. This is called regular expression. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6